# Difference of the impact forces between a loose material and a rigid body and between a cohesive material and a rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

Consider two cases:

1. Bag of 50 kg of loose sand is opened and emptied from 10m height onto a concrete floor
2. Bag of 50 kg of sand is dropped from 10m height onto a concrete floor

Q: What are the differences in terms of impact forces on the concrete floor from these two cases?

Comment: I believe you can answer this from Newton's 2nd law and possibly also from a pressure consideration.

Comment: The main difference is in the time it takes for things to come to a rest, which means change in momentum happens much slower in the opened bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impact force from the loose sand will generally be less—potentially far less—for at least the following reasons:

- The loose sand falls out of the bag over some finite duration and thus temporally distributes the impact time.
- The individual grains of loose sand are slowed down far more by air drag because their mass-to-area ratio is much lower than that of the much larger bag.
- Some of the impact energy of the loose sand can be dissipated by lateral motion, which doesn't really occur in the packed bag.

Notably, however, if the loose grains of sand were sufficiently laterally spaced and fell in concert in a vacuum, the total force would likely be *higher* because energy dissipation through compaction wouldn't occur, as it does in the bag.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. I don't grasp completely your last point. This applies in the case all grains of sand occupied a single horizontal surface and hit the floor at the same time? Or applies even if there were layers of surfaces staggered on top of each other? My intuition is that unless all sand grains fall at the same time the impact force will be smaller than the one from the sand bag...

Comment: Right—"in concert" here refers to simultaneous impact.